# no actualiza varios registros a la vez MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

quiero actualizar datos simultaeamente pero no lo realiza mi php.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($valor); $i++){
               
                    $valore = $valor[$i];
                    $idMese = $idmes[$i];
                   $idCapturas = $idCapturaMensual[$i];
                   

    $captura = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE capturamensual 
    SET valor='".$valore."',idMes='".$idMese."' where idCapturaMensual = '$idCapturas'");
    
    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, por favor lee [ask] y trata de ser mas específico

Comment: Los IDs de en tu base de datos son de tipo varchar o son enteros?

Answer (score 0):

Además de lo que te han dicho, tienes un error en

```
idCapturaMensual = '$idCapturas'
```

Ya que `idCapturaMensual` le estás asignando literalmente el *string* `$idCapturas`.

En el caso de ser un string debería ser:

```
idCapturaMensual = '".$idCapturas."'
```

O

```
idCapturaMensual = '{$idCapturas}'
```

En el caso que fuera un int debería ser lo mismo pero sin comillas simples ':

```
idCapturaMensual = ".$idCapturas."
```

O

```
idCapturaMensual = {$idCapturas}
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el tipo de dato de las columnas y modifica el PHP de la consulta, la puedes hacer en una variable separada

```
$sql = "UPDATE capturamensual SET valor = '{$valore}', idMes = '{$idMese}' WHERE idCapturaMensual = {$idCapturas};";
```

Si por ejemplo idMes o valor es int no le coloques las comillas